# Heavy use of present continuous

Tags: tenses, contemporary-english

"I am thinking ... ."

"I am guessing ... ."

"I am wanting ... ."

It might be a septuagenarian's illusion or it might actually be that this tense of verbs is now is (overly) heavy use.

Is there any way to account for it, other than fashion?

Comment: I'm really liking this question.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod: I shoulda known better.

Comment: you "should *of* known better."

Comment: I have no proof but I think it's just fashion.

Comment: The present continuous can be used as a form of politeness.'I am guessing you are from Illinois' is less intrusive than saying 'You're from Illinois, aren't you ?'

Comment: What about "I guess you are from Illinois" @Nigel J? I am not a native speaker and don't know which would be the "natural" way to say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These forms have been in use for a while, as marked forms to emphasise the immediacy or temporariness of the feeling. Neither the Corpus of Historical American English, nor Google ngrams confirms that there has been any great increase: in ngrams, "I am guessing" is about three times more prevalent now compared to the 1960s, (around 7 times more than the 1880s), but "I am believing" actually has fewer hits now than than the 1960s. But in each case, the incidence of the progressive is minute compared to the simple present.

I also have the impression that these forms are more common, despite the evidence of COHA and ngrams. I think part of the reason is that there is much more talk now about analysing one's own thoughts.

When I examine my thoughts, and discover that I have been acting as though I believed something that I did not know was there, and rationally I do not believe (such as "I have to please everybody all the time"), I really don't want to say that I believe that, but I prefer to say that at certain times I was believing that.

Comment: Thank you for this. Your ideas made me think about this a little more carefully.